# Obsocuring data by mounting a bind mount or non-empty volume in Docker

Tags: docker

What means please that sentence:

> If you mount a bind mount or non-empty volume into a directory in the
>   container in which some files or directories exist, these files or
>   directories are obscured by the mount, just as if you saved files into
>   /mnt on a Linux host and then mounted a USB drive into /mnt. The
>   contents of /mnt would be obscured by the contents of the USB drive
>   until the USB drive were unmounted. The obscured files are not removed
>   or altered, but are not accessible while the bind mount or volume is
>   mounted.

Is very vague to me, someone would please explain us what does mean please ?

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you spin up a docker container, that has a directory /etc/foo with files in it, and do a "docker run ... --mount type=bind,source=/home/user,target=/etc/foo" then the directory /etc/foo in your container will no longer appear to have the container's original files, instead it will appear to have the HOSTS /home/user files.